# Synchronized method in Spring WebFlux?

Tags: java, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I'm trying to persist a `singleton` class and I'd like to ensure it remains singleton. What is the proper method to synchronize method calls in `Spring WebFlux`?

I have the following service method:

```
public Mono<SingletonClass> saveOrUpdate(SingletonClass singletonClass) {
    return this.getTheSingletonClass()
               .map(someLogicAndSave)
               .switchIfEmpty(singletonClassRepository.save(singletonClass);
}
```

Should I add the synchronized keyword to the `saveOrUpdate` method?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Q: Synchronized method in Spring WebFlux? (Or any Mono/Flux)
- A: If you can, then find a better solution. First of all, do not use `synchronize` keyword when writing with Project reactor. Look at each function as a small part of the stream. *Project Reactor* gives you tools that have better control over the streams you are trying to synchronize. Much Much better control. Secondly, You shouldn't synchronize anything unless you are mutating something (which you should do it mainly for optimization purposes). Reacting programming is mainly about callbacks; when someone wants the result of the task, the task will run and when the task is finished, someone (not you) will call the function you provided with the result of the task as a parameter.
  Synchronization means waiting for a thread to finish to do something so the other thread can do that thing also. try to see if you can change your actual logic to be immutable so multiple threads can do that logic concurrently. **If not, then keep reading.**

---

When calling `saveOrUpdate`, you get back a Mono that represents the result of the task. the actual result will be there only when someone subscribes to the task (===the Mono you got from calling the function `saveOrUpdate`). In other words, `saveOrUpdate` only returns the description of the stream === what should the stream do (from top to bottom) when someone pushes a new value at the top of the stream.

- Q: Should I add the synchronized keyword to the `saveOrUpdate` method?
- A: No. As a conclusion of the above explanation, calling `saveOrUpdate` multiple times won't do much except creating and returning descriptions of streams. The methods that should (maybe) be synchronized are the methods that actually mutate something and may be called concurrently from multiple threads.

---

By now, you have the basic knowledge of what a stream is. The next step is to learn about multithreading in *Project Reactor* (The `Mono`/`Flux` library).

- Q: What is the proper method to synchronize method calls in Spring WebFlux?
- A: I'm not sure I understand what do you exactly mean. Is this question still relevant after everything I explained? If yes, consider rephrase it (edit the question).

---

#### Notes:

**Expression evaluations in streams:**

You should look closely on the expression: `singletonClassRepository.save(singletonClass)` in your example. A stream should execute only when someone subscribes to it. In your example, this piece of code is an expression that ***can*** and ***will*** be evaluated when the method `saveOrUpdate` is executing. As a result, part of the stream is executing even before someone subscribes to it (`singletonClassRepository.save(singletonClass)` and the rest of the stream will be executed only when someone subscribes to it.

It's not a bad design. But if `singletonClassRepository.save(singletonClass)` is doing some mutation, you should consider synchronize the method `saveOrUpdate`.

**How to synchronize**

**Only synchronize** with one of the tools which *Project Reactor* provides: `concatMap`,`flatMap` and so on.

Comment: I first thought that I understand it but the notes confused me. :) Why will it be evaluated without a subscription? Not only when the subscription callback enters that part of the pipe?

Comment: Remember that `1+1` is an expression. for example,  `increaseByOne(1+1)` will be evaluated to `increaseByOne(2)` which will be evaluated to `3`.

Comment: In your example, For each stream operator: map, filter,... you send a parameter. as a result, the operator create a new stream that contains the all the operators until him. the parameter is usually a lambda so it can't be evaluated anymore. but if you send `singletonClassRepository.save(singletonClass)` to your operator `switchIfEmpty`, then what you just sent is not a lambda and it can be evaluated by calling the function `save` and send it the param: `singletonClass`. the result of the method `save` will be the param to `switchIfEmpty`.

Comment: All in all, by calling `saveOrUpdate`, you only create the stream by sending params to every operator but the actual stream is not starting.

Comment: I think I now get it, thank you for the explanation and patience! Should I then wrap these functions with Mono.defer() or something?

Comment: My first note was just a "look on what you are doing.. it may be not what you meant to do". it doesn't mean its bad. I only wanted that you will know what parts of the code will run now (when the stream is in construction) or later (when there are subscriptions to the stream). But, if it fits your logic, go for it!

Comment: I edited the note by changing the "watch out" to "look closely". :)

Comment: How can you synchronize this with concatMap or flatMap? can you elaborate?